# How can I reference a different data set in a data region in SSRS?

Tags: ssrs-2012, reportbuilder3.0

I have a 3 datasets that I'd like to show on 1 report, with an additional one that controls some grouping.  The 3 datasets pull from the same sources, just different WHERE clause a different fields.

I've tried subreports, but it seems I can only add subreports if they've been uploaded to the server(?) or I'm building these in VS and the're part of a solution.  When I try to browse to a subreport in Report Builder, the Dialog Box asks me to `Look In: Recent Sites and Servers`, and lists nothing.

I've tried adding a footer to a group and inserting a new table and associating the new table with a different dataset, but it reverts to the dataset of the containing tablix.

An example of my Data:

```
Groupings
company|division|division_id
    a  |  div-a |  1
    a  |  div-b |  2

 Current Items
 item | division  
  ia  |   div-a
  ib  |   div-a
  ic  |   div-b

 New Items
 item  | division
  nia  | div-b
  nib  | div-b

 Ended by Discontinuation Reason
 reason |  division
  bad   |   div-a
  lame  |   div-b
  bad   |   div-a
```

Can anyone shed some light on how to get slightly disjointed data into the same report?  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Ideally, it would be best to have a single dataset. Instead of having a different query, each with a different `WHERE` clause, you should use a `INNER JOIN` and have just a single query/dataset.

For example, instead of having the following:

```
 SELECT 
  Field1
 ,Field2
 FROM Table1
 WHERE Field1 > 5

 SELECT 
  Field1
 ,Field2
 FROM Table1
 WHERE Field1 < 5

 SELECT 
  Field1
 ,Field2
 FROM Table1
 WHERE Field1 = 5
```

You should do:

```
 SELECT 
  G5.Field1
 ,G5.Field2
 ,L5.Field1
 ,L5.Field2
 ,E5.Field1
 ,E5.Field2

 FROM Table1
 INNER JOIN G5 
 ON G5.Field1 > 5   
 INNER JOIN L5 
 ON L5.Field1 < 5 
 INNER JOIN E5 
 ON E5.Field1 = 5
```

This way you only have one single dataset. And you can use the different fields however you wish in SSRS tables, knowing that each field is based on a specific criteria.

Comment: I think that would be fine if the data all had the same structure and size, but in my case DS1 and DS2 have the same structure, but DS3 is different.

Comment: It should definitely be possible if they're all from the same source, just with different WHERE fields (as indicated in your question). I think figuring this out, or maybe asking a separate question with additional details would be a good move.

Comment: However, you can definitely have different tables that connect to specific datasets all within a single SSRS report. Are you trying to create a single table, with fields coming from different datasets? If this is the case - there is a vlookup-type function in SSRS that you could use as a workaround that connects different SSRS tables with eachother.

Comment: This is the lookup function that allows you to connect two different SSRS tables, with each table using different datasets. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17318939/lookup-function-in-ssrs-report