# Adding 3 Multiple Data sets in SSRS

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

**Data Set 1

```
TransDate                           
JCTCardID                                                  
LPMJobCardNO                  
LPMMestriCode                   
MestriName                      
MestriCity                   
NoofEmps                       
GrossAmt
TransAmt
MestriAmt
SundayBounsAmt
NetAmt
CompName
```

DataSet 2 ( Multiple records having corsponding ProdcardId)

```
EmpCardDate                         
JCACardID                          
JobCardNO
MestriCode
EmpNo
EmpName
EmpAmt
```

DataSet3 ( Multiple records having corsponding ProdcardId)

```
ProdDate
ProdCardID
JobCardId
ShrimpVarity
ShrimpGrade
Kgs
Rate
Amount
```

Here I am requred to Add 3 DataSets and get  Bill Format in SSRS

```
Bill Format
===========================================================
Card data    Card ID  MestriName  City Name     No of Emps               
===========================================================
01/02/2020  101001    Ravindra    Bhimavaram       2

Name of the Employees:
========================================================
1   xxxxxxx
2  xxxxxxxxx
=======================================================
Grade        Varity            Kgs         Rate    Amount

xxxx         xxxxx             xxx           xxx    xxxxx
xxxx         xxxxx             xxxx          xxx    xxxxx

                                          gross amt xxxx

Transport amt                                       xxxx
mestri amt                                          xxxx
bonuns amt                                          xxxx
                                                   -----
                                                   xxxxx
                                                  ------
```

requesting any one can help me how to connecting 3 data sets in SSRS

Comment: Is there any reason you cannot combine these datasets into a single dataset on SQL Server. That would make the whole thing much easier.

Comment: It would be good if you shared what steps you have taken, or what you have tried, then we can help build upon your solution.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot Add multiple Dataset to a Table or Tablix in Report.
What you could do, use Subreports or Lookup Expressions to get data from different Dataset in your Report.

I personally Like and recommend Subreport, but you can follow through your specific req.

[SubReport 1 Example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-design/add-a-subreport-and-parameters-report-builder-and-ssrs?view=sql-server-ver15)

[SubReport 2 Example](https://www.tutorialgateway.org/ssrs-subreports/)

[SubReport 3 Example](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/5649/multidetail-reports-using-sub-reports-in-sql-server-reporting-services/)

[SubReport 4 Example](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/195017/SSRS-Series-Part-II-Working-with-Subreports-DrillD)

[SubReport 5 Example](http://www.sqlcircuit.com/2012/11/ssrs-how-to-create-subreport.html)

---

[Lookup 1 Example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-design/report-builder-functions-lookup-function?view=sql-server-ver15)

[Lookup 2 Example](https://samueleresca.net/lookup-functions-ssrs/)

[Lookup 3 Example](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2141/sql-server-reporting-services-lookup-lookupset-and-multilookup-functions/)

[Lookup 4 Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17318939/lookup-function-in-ssrs-report)