# How to get the difference between two datasets from two tables in SSRS report

Tags: reporting-services

I have a SSRS report with two datasets. My report has two tables with fields from dataset 1 and fields from dataset 2 .  I am trying to compare the difference between a column which both fields have. I used this expression :

[image]

`=Sum(Fields!Current.Value, "dataset1") - Sum(Fields!Current1.Value, "dataset2")`

But It gives me only the over all total showing on all rows in the table.

I need help on how to get the total on each rows

I used : `=Lookup(Fields!CHGHOURS.Value, Fields!CHGHOURS.Value, Fields!CHGHOURS.Value, "dataset1"  )`

This is showing me a few values from dataset2, Not even the value is showing from dataset1.

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Lookup function in SSRS report](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17318939/lookup-function-in-ssrs-report)

Comment: You could just compare the textbox values. ReportItems!Textbox1.Value - ReportItems!Textbox2.Value

Comment: I figured it out later. Hence I have rows . I had to include the rows in the lookup to get results.        EG:  =Lookup(Fields!GROUP5.Value, Fields!GROUP5.Value, Fields!Current.Value, "std_SP") - Lookup(Fields!GROUP5.Value, Fields!GROUP5.Value, Fields!Current1.Value, "DataSet1")  .    I has five row groups ,  .  But I still have a problem, I can't get the total on each groups.  The rows working fine  and the grand total is working well. But I can get the total on each group.  Any help please.